# Role based dashboard in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
CREATE TABLE `role_details` (
  `role_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_desc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rights` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)
) 



CREATE TABLE `user_details` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
```

This is my database schema. I am using spring security.
But I am confused...what I need to write in **spring-security.xml** ?

```
 <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "SELECT * FROM hmis_db.user_details where display_name=? and status='active'"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "**QUESTION**  " />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Actually, I want to create Role based dashboard. and 'rights' in role_details table that specifies the access menu list..and according it it will generate role based dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I can't see the relationship between your UserDetails table and the RoleDetails one, maybe I'm losing something.

When I have made such a kind of entities schemas, I allways made a 1-to-n relations between Users and roles, so one user can have one role or more.

But assumming you are conguring a 1-1 relation from user to role, and assuming the ROLE_xxx you are looking for is on the role field in UserDetails table, your authorities-by-username-query must be more or less like this:

```
"select display_name as username, role as authority from user_details where display_name =?  "
```

If the field role in user_details is the foreign key which must match the field role_name in role_details, and rigths are actually the authorities which are referenced in access elements of security_intercept urls, it should be this way:

```
    "select u.display_name as username, r.rights as authority 
from user_details as u INNER JOIN role_details as r ON u.role = r.role_name  
where u.display_name =?  "
```

But here you might have a trouble if rights are a comma separated list of authorities. authorities-by-username-query expects to receive a list of rows with an authority in each of this rows. If this is what you were seeking, you should consider changing the schema or making even a view of the tables which returns a right per row result

EDIT: I should do this way:

[image]

This is the creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `role_details` (
  `role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_desc` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `role_authority` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_details` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_time` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_role_details` (
  `user_details_user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `role_details_role_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_details_user_id`, `role_details_role_id`),
  INDEX `fk_user_details_has_role_details_role_details1_idx` (`role_details_role_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_user_details_has_role_details_user_details_idx` (`user_details_user_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_details_has_role_details_user_details`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_details_user_id`)
    REFERENCES `user_details` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_details_has_role_details_role_details1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`role_details_role_id`)
    REFERENCES `role_details` (`role_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Note I deleted column 'role' in user_details, renamed 'rights' to 'role_authority' in role_details and changed 'status' from varchar to tinyint(1) to use it as boolean.

Then, the user details sqls:

```
        users-by-username-query=
    "SELECT display_name as username, password, status as enabled
FROM user_details as u WHERE u.display_name = ? and status = 1;"

        authorities-by-username-query=
    "Select u.display_name as username, r.role_authority as authority 
        FROM 
        user_details as u 
        INNER JOIN user_role_details as urd ON u.user_id = urd.user_details_user_id 
        INNER JOIN role_details as r ON urd.role_details_role_id = r.role_id
        WHERE u.display_name = ?"
```

This way you can have multiple roles binded to each user

Comment: can you please provide me proper schema and related queries?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to following link that covers basics and example http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/blog/spring-security-with-roles-and-rights

Once you familiarize yourself with basics, please look deeper into Spring Security documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html before you implement that code for production.

If you are using Spring Security 4, you may prefer annotations based configurations like

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("userpwd").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("adminpwd").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll() 
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");

    }
}
```